# Module location of self-written Perl module

Tags: perl, module

I am trying to use my module in a script.

I know that you have to provide a module location and would like to provide the path in the script. However, I get the error message:

> No such file or directory

This is my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib "C:/Users/XPS13/Documents/Uni/UEProgramming";

use Bioinformatics;

my $DNAinput = "restriction_test.txt";

open (my $FH_DNA_in, "<", $DNAinput) or die " Can't open file $DNAinput: $!\n";

print "Pattern match for input file \n";
print (Bioinformatics::Pattern($FH_DNA_in), "\n"); #  applying module function
```

And this is my module

```
package Bioinformatics; # making module, 1st line contains name

use strict; # module uses strict and warnings 
use warnings;

sub Pattern {
my $count = "0";
my ($DNAinput) = @_;
open (my $FH_DNA_in, "<", $DNAinput) or die " Can't open file $DNAinput: $!\n";
    while (my $line = <$FH_DNA_in>) {
        if ($line =~ /[AG]GATC[TC]/ ) { 
        ++ $count;
        }
}
    print "Your sequence contains the pattern [AG]GATC[TC] $count times\n";
}

    1; # last line
```

#### Answer:

The module location works.

The error occured because I opened the file twice (in the script and the module)

When opening it only within the module, it works. The updated script is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib "C:/Users/XPS13/Documents/Uni/UEProgramming";

use Bioinformatics;

my $DNAinput = "restriction_test.txt";

print "Pattern match for input file \n";
print (Bioinformatics::Pattern($DNAinput), "\n"); #  applying module function
```

Comment: Are you sure that's because of the `use` statement? It sounds more like that's an error from opening a file. Your `use lib` looks fine. Have you tried using backslashes ``\`` instead of forward slashes `/`? You need to escape them with extra backslashes, so it's ``\\`` in double quotes`""`.

Comment: You were right it was a error with the file itself and the use lib command aktually worked! Thank's!

Comment: Good. I'm voting to close because of a typo.

Comment: maybe it was a typo but when I just removed one of the filehandles it worked. Therfore I guess the error was due to opening it twice

Comment: Ah. No. You opened the file and then passed the file handle to the function, where you used it as a file name. The handle got serialized, turning it into a weird string. Try printing the file handle to see what I mean. Obviously that file then doesn't exist. So it's not the typo close reason. I'll remove the vote and wrote up an answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: In the future, please provide the output you actually received!

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from the `open` inside of your function. In your script, you open a filehandle called `$FH_DNA_in` and you then pass that filehandle variable to your function

```
#        V
open (my $FH_DNA_in, "<", $DNAinput) or die " Can't open file $DNAinput: $!\n";
#                              V
print (Bioinformatics::Pattern($FH_DNA_in), "\n"); #  applying module function
```

In the function, you use it as the path to the file to open.

```
sub Pattern {
    my $count = "0";
    my ($DNAinput) = @_; # first arg was the filehandle!

    #                           | this is the old filehandle
    #        V different var    V
    open (my $FH_DNA_in, "<", $DNAinput) or die " Can't open file $DNAinput: $!\n";
```

The `$FH_DNA_in` in that function is a new lexical variable. It has nothing to do with the old filehandle, which ended up in `$DNAinput`, because that is what you passed as the first (and only) argument.

If you use the filehandle where a path is expected, Perl will serialize it. That looks something like this:

```
$ perl -E "open my $fh, '>', 'tmp'; say $fh;"
GLOB(0x26ba8c)
```

So it tries to look for a file with that name, which of course doesn't exist.

You should have seen a full error message that looked like this:

> Can't open file GLOB(0x26ba8c): No such file or directory

Note that it doesn't tell you in which line the error occurred because you included a newline `\n` in the argument to `die`. If you had not done that it would have been more obvious that loading the module worked because the message would have been more along the lines of

> Can't open file GLOB(0x26ba8c): No such file or directory at C:/Users/XPS13/Documents/Uni/UEProgramming/Bioinformatics.pm line 9.

Comment: @E.L: As **simbabque** says, your *real* error message would be something like `Can't open file GLOB(0x26ba8c): No such file or directory` but that's not what you told us. If you ask for help then for goodness sake don't remove bits of information that you've decided are irrelevant. You've posted a question because you can find the cause of the problem, so you're not really in a position to determine what evidence is relevant and what isn't.